# mysql_safe_query()

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I have been thinking of a sql-injection free implementation in dynamic languages. Here's what I came with. All the code was written just for fun and learning purposes.

I would like to share it and get some feedback about it.
Mainly about *performance*, *efficiency* and *usability*.

All the information you need is directly written to documentation inside the script:

```
<?php

/// @license public domain
/// @brief This function works exactly like mysql_real_query, but it escapes all data for you.
/// This function is an example how dynamic languages can deal with sql injection.
/// And was created mainly for learning purpose.
/// There are two prototypes for this function:
///     mysql_safe_query(string $format[, ...])
///     mysql_safe_query(mysql $mysql, string $format [, ...])
/// Example:
///     mysql_safe_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = ? AND b = ? LIMIT 0, ?", 20.21, "mal'form'ed", 12);
/// Output:
///     SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 20.21 AND b = X'6d616c27666f726d276564' LIMIT 0, 12
/// @param resource $mysql Optional - pass a $mysql link
/// @param string $format Format of the query with placeholders ('?') instead of values
/// @param mixed ... values/data to be queried with
/// @return A result from mysql_real_query, or false with an error generated when
/// number of parameters is larger than the number of placeholder.
/// @warning In case that there's more placeholders than parameters, they will be replaced with NULL
/// @note You don't have to call mysql_set_charset before invoking this function, since this
/// function is not using mysql_real_escape_string but bin2hex instead:
/// @see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html
/// @note You can't bind keywords, as all strings are escaped
/// @note Although mysql_* functions are deprecated they are used by this function to maintain
/// MySQL C API compatibilty. Feel free to change it to whatever api you are using.
function mysql_safe_query(/*$mysql, $format, ...*/)
{
    // get all arguments passed to this function
    $args = func_get_args();

    // check whether first parameter is a link
    if (is_resource($args[0]))
        $link = array_shift($args);

    // get $format argument passed
    $query = array_shift($args);
    $offset = 0;

    // for each placeholder at $offset do the following
    while (FALSE !== ($offset = strpos($query, '?', $offset)))
    {
        // fetch next parameter passed
        $param = array_shift($args);

        // if next parameter is a string, we must escape it
        if (is_string($param))
            $param = "X'" . bin2hex($param) . "'";
        // datatype NULL should became unquoted NULL string
        else if (is_null($param))
            $param = "NULL";

        // now just replace the placeholder with actual value
        $query = substr_replace($query, strval($param), $offset, 1);
    }

    // if we got any unprocessed arguments, its an error
    if (count($args))
    {
        // emit error
        trigger_error("Count of bound parameters doesnt equal to count of passed parameters!", E_USER_ERROR);
        return false;
    }

    // if we haven't got a link
    if (!isset($link))
        return mysql_real_query($query);

    // we got the link
    return mysql_real_query($link, $query);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Validating the arguments

You validate the arguments a bit late,
after processing the query placeholders:

> ```
> // if we got any unprocessed arguments, its an error
> if (count($args))
> {
>     // emit error
>     trigger_error("Count of bound parameters doesnt equal to count of passed parameters!", E_USER_ERROR);
>     return false;
> }
> ```

For one thing, the error message is not accurate:
it is triggered when there are more arguments than query placeholders.
If there are too few arguments, then any excess placeholders are replaced with `NULL`, as duly noted in the documentation.

It would be somewhat cleaner to check the parameter count and the `?` count as early as possible.
Admittedly, that would incur an additional string search step compared to your current solution, and as such less efficient.

Is the `return false` necessary? On my system the execution stops at `trigger_error`.

#### Limitations

It's of concern, and at least should be mentioned in the documentation that a query cannot have `?` characters in SQL string values. For example this won't work as expected:

```
mysql_safe_query("UPDATE Posts SET question = 'How are you?' WHERE id = ?", 12);
```

Ideally `?` symbols within SQL strings (enclosed within pairs of single quotes) should not be treated as placeholders,
but obviously that would make the implementation significantly more complex.

#### Nitpicks

It's generally recommended to have one statement per line.
This kind of loop condition is considered tricky, hard to read, error-prone:

> ```
> while (FALSE !== ($offset = strpos($query, '?', $offset)))
> ```

Although slightly longer, but less confusing to write this way:

```
while (true)
{
    $offset = strpos($query, '?', $offset);
    if (FALSE === $offset) break;
```